# Updating an imported CSV file in pgadmin4

Tags: sql, csv, create-table

I created a table in pgadmin 4 successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE JAN21 (
    asofdate DATE,
    Company VARCHAR(50),
    SECTOR VARCHAR(50),
    INDUSTRY VARCHAR(50),
    COUNTRY VARCHAR (50)
);
```

I imported a CSV file successfully using:

```
SELECT * FROM JAN21

COPY JAN21 FROM 'C:\Users\doesnotmatterwhatthissays' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

My question is: I will update the CSV file every Friday with new data, if I execute the same query with updated data, I see my new data, however, I also duplicate the previous values.

What is best practice for updating a CSV file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand as you mentioned "updating a CSV file" and not the table you created. Maybe use a staging table. Truncate the staging on each load. Join staging and main table - Jan21 - to find new data and only load new data. This may or may not be what you need.